# Mute Debug Messages from Plugins

Tags: php, errors, debug, notices, deprecation

I have an older plugin installed that is firing all these `PHP Deprecated` and `PHP Notices` in my debug.log every time a page loads. **Is it possible to mute `PHP Deprecated` and `PHP Notices` but ONLY for files in my plugins directory?** I value a clean debug.log as it helps with making sure my code is error-free during development, but this kind of stuff makes it all messy.

---

More Details:
I don't want to turn off all PHP notices because I like to have those to make sure my own code isn't creating any notices.

This plugin is something my client wants that is not worth the time to fix/replace/build from scratch, so I'd prefer to keep it.